# Setting HTML and BODY CSS using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, onload

In CSS, to set the height of a div so that it stretches from the top of the page to the bottom is done like so:

```
html, body, #xdiv {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

The problem is, this executes straight away, so when the text or content loads, it's not 100% any more. My question is, can I use Jquery or JS to set the above after page load?

Comment: what have you tried? if you know jquery it should be fairly straight forward.

Comment: You mean like with `$(window).load(function() {`?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense, you didn't explain what xdiv is, but if they were one within the other they would always fill 100% of the screen. Setting it later on would make no difference.

Comment: xdiv is a div.. And no, it doesn't do it automatically since I've had to manually set it with CSS. And it worked fine until I started to add content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `load`:

```
$(window).load(function() {
   $('html, body, #xdiv').css({ "height": "100%", "min-height": "100%"});
});
```

Comment: I think you messed up with the brackets, but let me see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:  http://jsfiddle.net/00ho9kgv/

To vertically-center content, you'll need to wrap and use `display: table`, etc: http://jsfiddle.net/00ho9kgv/1/